# ASP.NET MVC set default value in controller for view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

forgive me I am just learning mvc. I have an application that manages projects and utilities. For each project, there can be multiple utilities. There is a "Projects" page that lists all of the projects, and if you click on a Project, it lists all of the utilities associated with it. There is also a button on the project screen to allow you to add Utilities to that project. So, when you click on the project and then click the "Add Utility" button, it pulls up a form to allow you to add a utility to that project. The form has the project ID, utility ID and owner pre-filled, taken from the project controller information.  What I am trying to do is set a default on one of the fields in the Utility (relocation expense) to 0.00. So, that, if it is not changed by the user, it shows as 0.00 in the database. Seems simple, right?

Here is my code in the controller currently for the Get method of the Utility (advice from a previous thread) and what I changed it to.

Before:

```
 // GET: /Utility/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectID)
        {
            CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);
            return View();
        }
```

After:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectID)
{
    CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);
    // initialize the model and set its properties
    UtilityDTO model = new UtilityDTO
    {
        Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M
    };
    // return the model
    return View(model);
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Est_Relocation_Expense, "{0:0.00}")
```

This works great...it adds the default value to the field...however, it loses the pre-filled project id, utility id, and owner information (does not pre-fill) that it retrieved from the project controller.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here? I can provide other code from the controller as well, if needed, but it is very long so not sure what else to post.

Added view for project id:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project_ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 CreateEditFieldNamesSpan" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.VBProjectIDAndName, "---Select Project---")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project_ID)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the code for the `CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit` method.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown that could cause you to _lose the values for project ID, utility ID and owner_ since nothing ever sets them. Show the relevant sections of the view where you generate the controls for each of those properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke not sure how much I can post...can I post the whole file? I can't find where it is assigning these. It is sorting the data various ways based on options chosen in the form to display by each field. And, displaying different data based on owner...I removed that code....just a bunch of "case" sections.

Comment: You have case statements inside a view??. Start by just showing how you generate the dropdownlist for the ProjectID property and we can work from there

Comment: @StephenMuecke lots of case statements and lots of "if"....show different set of utiltiies for different owners. The cases are if they choose certain fields to sort on. I added the code to display the utilities. Looking for the code to generate the project id.

Comment: @NightOwl, The code you have shown is not relevant and should be deleted. Its the `Create.cshtml` view that is relevant (that's where you claiming that the values are being lost)

Comment: You should also remove the line `var ControllerProjectIDAndName = ...` and change the following line to `ViewBag.VBProjectIDAndName = Projects;` (its just pointless to create a second Selectlist from the first one)

Comment: I desperately need an asp.net mvc training course. I added the code that is in the view for the project id drop-down list.

Comment: For the dropdownlist you have shown, the selected option will always be the first one because the value of property `Project_ID` has not been set. If you change the GET method to `UtilityDTO model = new UtilityDTO{ Project_ID = ProjectID, Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M };` then it will be correctly selected.

Comment: When I try to Build, I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type "int?" to "int". An explicit conversion exists. (Are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Ok, then it needs to be `Project_ID = ProjectID.Value,`

Comment: It worked!! You are a life-saver! I noticed that the default works in the edit.cshtml as well, even though I did not specify the format  "{0:0.00}", and I am using "@Html.EditorFor(model=>". Does that matter? Should I change it to TextBoxFor and add the format?

Comment: Oh no, I was wrong...it didn't work in the edit.cshtml. I probably need to put the same code in the edit get method, huh?

Comment: If you add the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyInEditMode)]` attribut to the property it will work with `EditorFor()` - whatever you prefer

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for hanging with me on this. I am looking for a class. Hopefully I can answer questions one day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of the properties in the model before you pass the model to the view. Your currently only setting at value for `Est_Relocation_Expense`. If you want the dropdownlist to display the option associated with the `ProjectID` parameter in your method, then modify your method to

```
public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectID)
{
    CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);
    UtilityDTO model = new UtilityDTO
    {
        Project_ID = ProjectID, // add this
        Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Side note: It is not necessary to send the value of `ProjectID` to the `CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit()` method. From your now deleted code, that was being used only to set the `selectedValue` property of `SelectList` which is ignored when binding a dropdownlist to a property. You need only use the constructor which is `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)`

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help!